# Spatial polygon intersection - multiple resulting polygons

Tags: r, polygon, spatial, intersection

I am working on the intersection of polygons using the R spatial tools `rgeos::gIntersection` and/or `raster::intersect`. In my case the result of the intersection is two polygons due to the shape of one of the polygons (`Lpoly`) used to do the intersection. However, from the `summary()` function it looks it is only one feature that is created?! How can I access the two geometries resulting from the intersect process? Furthermore I'd like to select only one of the resulting polygons based on a criteria of covering a particular spatial point (coordinate pair):

```
A <- c(0,0)
B <- c(0,3)
C <- c(2,3)
D <- c(2,1)
E <- c(3,1)
F <- c(3,3)
G <- c(5,3)
H <- c(5,0)
Lpoly <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(rbind(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H))),1)))
plot(Lpoly)

A2 <- c(1,2)
B2 <- c(1,3)
C2 <- c(4,3)
D2 <- c(4,2)
intersect_poly <-  SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(rbind(A2,B2,C2,D2))),1)))
plot(intersect_poly,col="red",add=T) 

i <- intersect(Lpoly,intersect_poly)
i_rgeos <- rgeos::gIntersection(Lpoly,intersect_poly)
summary(i_rgeos)

plot(i_rgeos,add=T,col="green")
```

How to select only one polygon and/or get unique features for each resulting polygon? How can I access the resulting polygon that also covers the coordinates `c(1.5,2.5)`?

**Solution approach #1:**
I found a solution based on:

```
i_rgeos <- disaggregate(i_rgeos)
i_rgeos <- i_rgeos[as.vector(which(over(i_rgeos,p)>0)),] #where p = spatial point of interest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure in `rgeos` how to do it, but using the `sf` package, we can easily cast shapefiles to different types, in this case from MULTIPOLYGON to POLYGON, we just have to first cast `i_rgeos` to a simple feature.

```r
library(sf)

st_as_sf(i_rgeos) %>% st_cast("POLYGON")
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 0 fields
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 2 xmax: 4 ymax: 3
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#>                         geometry
#> 1 POLYGON ((1 3, 2 3, 2 2, 1 ...
#> 2 POLYGON ((3 2, 3 3, 4 3, 4 ...
```